# How to layout/draw a centered hexagonal number in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, layout, graphics

How can you draw a [centered hexagonal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number) like this:

[image]

The **18th** centered hexagonal number has **919 dots**, so the goal is to make it so it can draw at least 919 dots in a predefined width/height square (width/height will be variables passed in from the outside).

So say the width is 800px and we want a gap of at least 8px between points in all directions, how can you accomplish this? It is a bit of a brain-twister for me.

The recurrence relation for generating the grid is:

[image]

At every depth `n`, there are `n` points in a straight line on each shell.

Here's where I'm stuck (I'm stuck at how to compute the position of each dot in the grid layout).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.width = canvas.width
context.height = canvas.height

const MAX_DEPTH = 18
const MIN_RADIUS = 4
// How to calculate the computed radius? Not quite sure.
// And probably shrink the gap if we don't have enough space, but that can come later.
const IDEAL_GAP = 4
const MAX_OUTER_RADIUS = canvas.width / MAX_DEPTH
const DETERMINED_RADIUS = MAX_OUTER_RADIUS - IDEAL_GAP

console.log('DETERMINED_RADIUS', DETERMINED_RADIUS)

const COLOR = [
  'red',
  'orange',
  'yellow',
  'green',
  'blue',
  'violet'
]

const centerX = canvas.width / 2
const centerY = canvas.height / 2

let d = 1
while (d <= MAX_DEPTH) {
  // Number of dots in this shell
  let n = d * 6
  let i = 0
  while (i < n) {
    // How to layout the dots according to the first image?
    const side = Math.floor(i / d) + 1
    drawCircle({
      cx: centerX - (d * MAX_OUTER_RADIUS),
      cy: centerY - (d * MAX_OUTER_RADIUS),
      r: DETERMINED_RADIUS,
      depth: d
    })
    i++
  }
  d++
}

function drawCircle({ cx, cy, r, depth }) {
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(cx, cx, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
  context.fillStyle = COLOR[depth - 1] ?? 'black'
  context.fill()
}
```

```html
<h1>Canvas below</h1>
<!-- small canvas so you can see on SO -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<h1>Canvas above</h1>
```

I don't see how to apply the math to calculate the position of the dots according to the hexagonal grid layout in the first image. How can that be done?

FWIW, my goal is to eventually be able to draw all the different types of [centered *polygonal* numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_polygonal_number), and more generically, all [polygonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number) (and [star numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_number)), so this is the first baby step, in learning how to use sin/cos and such to calculate the positions on the polygon where the dots go.

I am a React developer mainly, so canvas and sin/cos isn't my goto set of tools and I have a big learning curve ahead.

Comment: I found your question interesting and I wrote a JavaScript program to generate centered polygonal numbers in SVG format. Check it here: https://ouilogique.com/files/2024-02-08-centered_polygonal_numbers/centered_polygonal_numbers.html.

Comment: @nico Beautiful! You did it!

Comment: Thanks, that was a fun project to do.
You can use my function that generates coordinates to understand the math behind it and to create your own version with React. It should also help you with your other project with star numbers. I can also answer your questions if you have any, but try to be more specific than in your original post.